# Why does `setTimeout` not recur in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, settimeout

```
var arrayProcessTimeout;
arrayProcessTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('hard');
  return null;
}, 50);
```

That's my code in `Node.js` and one would expect it to output `hard` constantly.. but it doesn't. It outputs it once and that's it.

Comment: No need to downvote - it was a simple mistake.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe you want to use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval) instead of [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout).